# Why am I getting squigglies for my gridview inside `<asp:content>`?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm not sure why I'm getting this informational message for my gridview inside my webforms `<asp:content>` tags that uses `masterpagefile`? Page still works despite that.

[image]

Comment: Does it prevent building and running? I often experience this in VS on the legacy projects I support. I often experience what I'd call "phantom" errors in VS, there will be hundreds of compiler errors listed. As I double click each one, it's as if VS parses the file and they disappear. It usually occurs where the codebehind references a control that is defined in the ASP markup.

I think this is a glitch that MS is not incentivised to fix

Comment: Agree with above comments. In fact doing a rebuild all and re open of the page tends to fix this